# ServiceBus message delivery time reliable?

Tags: azure, servicebus

I'm working on creating an events system with Azure ServiceBus, I find events generally hits reliably at the scheduled time I had them set to run - so if event 'pop' is supposed to run at 12:30pm it generally would be delivered at that time to my reciever.

I wanted to know is there a guarantee that events are always fired within the scheduled time or is that more of a suggested time and the system can get clogged and backlogged causing longer queues to form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few differences between *messages* (which are handled with Service Bus) and *events*, as you can see in the article [Choose between Azure messaging services - Event Grid, Event Hubs, and Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services).

> An event is a lightweight notification of a condition or a state change. The publisher of the event has no expectation about how the event is handled. The consumer of the event decides what to do with the notification. Events can be discrete units or part of a series.
>
> [...]
>
> A message is raw data produced by a service to be consumed or stored elsewhere. The message contains the data that triggered the message pipeline.

It sounds like you need a reliable way to have a timer trigger execute on a specific time. Service Bus is not the correct service for that, since "the message enquing time does not mean that the message will be sent at that time. It will get enqueued, but the actual sending time depends on the queue's workload and its state." (see [`BrokeredMessage.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.scheduledenqueuetimeutc?view=azure-dotnet#remarks)).

For handling the triggering in a reliable way, you could use services like [Logic Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/) (if you want to create it low-code/no-code) or [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) (for the Serverless solution with code).

If you're actually looking for *events*, consider [Event Grid](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-grid).